# How to slice all the columns except first column in numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to slice the columns of numpy array in python.

How to print all the columns except first one? Imagine I have large  dimensions of numpy array not the simple one.

Answer (score 5):

First, create an array in Python, then, use slicing to extract everything but the first column:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
sliced = a[:,1:]
print(sliced)
```

output:

```
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```

Comment: @GovindaKc, no problem. If my response answered your question, please accept it :-)

Comment: I accepted the solution but is not displayed @Riley. It says: because of less than 125 reputations, scores are not displayed :(